# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in C:\wamp\www\MbaGurukul\quiz.php on line 19

Tags: php, html

I am a php newbie who is trying to create a quiz. Most similar questions here say there is a non matching number of braces, but I cannot find any such case in my code. How do I resolve this?

```
<?php require_once 'connect.php';?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Mbagurukul Quiz</title>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/style.css'/>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Dummy Quiz</h1>
<?php $response=mysql_query("select * from questions") or die(mysql_error()); ?>
<form method='post' id='quiz_form'>
<?php while($result=mysql_fetch_array($response)){ 
 Print "<th>" .$result['ID'] . "</th> <td>" .$result['Question'] . "</td>" ;?> 
 <input type="radio" name="Option_2" value=result['Option_2']> result['Option_2']
 <input type="radio" name="Option_1" value=result['Option_1']> result['Option_1']
 <input type="radio" name="Option_3" value=result['Option_3']> result['Option_3']
 <input type="radio" name="Option_4" value=result['Option_4']> result['Option_4']
<?php ? ?>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I am getting the error

> ( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?' in C:\wamp\www\MbaGurukul\quiz.php on line 19

Comment: Yep it's in here `<?php ? ?>`

Comment: I made an error typing here, but in my code it's <?php } ?>

Comment: You should edit your question then. People are answering with the right answers, yet if that's not the problem....(`?`).

Comment: I realized where I'd made the error. There is a difference between     <?php}?> and <?php } ?> , which I didn't realize. That was causing the error.

Comment: @Apoorv: you aren't making any sense, you did say you made a typo here, but you are still posting the wrong code?

Comment: @ApoorvAshutosh Well then, you should post it as an **answer**. You should also take `Samuel Liew's` suggestion into consideration about your values. Then again, `Samuel Liew` came up with the answer. It's only fitting that you accept his answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the fourth last line:

```
<?php ? ?>
```

to:

```
<?php } ?>
```

Do note also, that your html is not well-formed. TH and TD is not allowed in form, only a TR, which in turn has to be in a TABLE.

If you intend to use a table instead, wrap the INPUTS in a TD.

If you are intending to print out the value of `value=result['Option_2']`, you should be using PHP instead:

```
value="<?php echo result['Option_2']; ?>"
```

Comment: Apparently the OP made an error in his original posted question. Sit and wait...